# Check format for Continous integration

Tags: go, makefile, continuous-integration

I am trying to write a Makefile command that will output an error if the Go code is not correctly formatted. This is for a CI step. I am struggling with how to get it working in the make file. This solution works on the bash command line:

```
! gofmt -l . 2>&1 | read
```

But copying this into the Makefile:

```
ci-format:
    @echo "$(OK_COLOR)==> Checking formatting$(NO_COLOR)"
    @go fmt ./...
    @! gofmt -l . 2>&1 | read
```

I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: read: arg count
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These days, I use [golangci-lint](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint), which includes `gofmt` checking as an option.

But if for some reason you want to do this yourself, the command I previously used for precisely that purpose is:

```
diff -u <(echo -n) <(gofmt -d ./)
```

See, for example, the [.travis.yml](https://github.com/flimzy/go-pouchdb/blob/master/.travis.yml) files on one of my projects.